# “Exception calling ”Substring“ with ”2“ argument(s): ”startIndex cannot be larger than length of string" Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, search, substring, move

I need to search through directory's find files (they all have the same name-layout). Look position 9,10,11 in the filename, create a directory bases on the 3 characters and move all files with the same 3 characters at position 9,10,11 to the directory created..

The code works but for every file it finds I get the error

"Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."

all files are minimal of length of 25 characters. 
The code shown is without the move part of the files as isn't relevant for the error.

```
dir -recurse| %{ 
$id = $_.Name.SubString(8,3); 
if(-not (Test-Path $id)) {mkdir $id}; }
```

Comment: `dir -recurse` -> `dir ???????????* -recurse`

Comment: Thanx, works like a charm.. If you have the time? can you explain why this works?

Comment: You have files somewhere in the directory hierarchy that have names of less than 8 characters, hence the error from substring. The wildcard pattern `???????????*` will only glob files that have 11+ characters in the name (`?` means exactly one char, `*` means anything)

Comment: Got the feeling the gods of PowerShell always come from the netherlands ;)
One question in generell, if a question is answered in the comments who will write the answer so that the question is solved?

Comment: Thanx, helps a lot. There are over 20k files..

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, 

Redd has a point. Could you make your comment as an answer? Than we can sign off en give credit where credit is due ;-)

Comment: Consider it done :)

Comment: So all files not minimal length 25 characters then.

Answer (score 0):

> "Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string."

This error indicates that at least one of the file system items returned by `dir -recurse` has a name of less than 8 characters.

You can either supply a wildcard filter to `Get-ChildItem` (aka. `dir`) that matches 11 or more characters:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter ???????????* -Recurse
```

or you could filter out any item with less than 11 characters in the name using `Where-Object`:

```
# You could either use regex
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where-Object Name -match '.{11}'
# or inspect the Length property directly
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.Name.Length -ge 11}
```